# Android-emulator  AVD Window Size

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My question seems to be stupid, but I really could not solve it.

I am using eclipse to develop android applications, but when I run the emulator AVD it has a fixed window size (very huge on my computer screen), so I can't see the rest of the Android screen.

Can you help me?

Comment: I found the I can use the commands to manage the emulator window (window <scale>), but how and where?

Comment: See [this SO answer][1] for a permanent solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/android-emulator-screen-too-tall/4963984#4963984

Answer (score 47):

If the size of the emulator is too big. You can resize it by:

1. Run > Run Configurations
2. Pick the "Target" tab
3. Scroll down to Additional Emulator Command Line Options and put in: `-scale 0.8` or another number

Comment: This works in Android Studio, too! TY

Comment: Using 0.8.4, I went into Run Configurations, Tab: Emulator, and entered "-scale 0.6" in "Additional command line options", however, it has no effect.

Comment: In Android Studio, you can go AVD->Advanced, then "2px = 1px on device" to half the size.

Comment: ^ I think you mean 1dp on device = 2px on screen. This will produce an emulator at half it's defined size.

Answer (score 25):

Here can help you:

- Menu -> Windows -> Android SDK and AVD manager
- Choose your AVD then select <kbd>Edit</kbd> button
- In line **Skin** you choose **HVGA** for built-in or custom your size resolution...

HVGA will allow the emulator to fit on your screen.

Answer (score 21):

type this command

```
adb emu window scale 0.6
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's what worked for me:

- In eclipse, go Run -> Run configurations.
- Select the Target tab.
- In the `Additional Emulator Command Line Options` field type `-skin ­­320x480` or some other resolution appropriate for you.
- Click "Apply" button.
- Click the "Run" button.

I tried the `-scale 0.8` option but it didn't work well because although the screen size was reduced, the color looked like 8 bit color... or worse. It was entirely unusable since the flash screen was almost entirely white.

The `-skin ­­320x480` option produced an emulator of an appropriate size with no graphics issues.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to *Android AVD manager* and chose the device.
2. Click `start >> Launch options >>> Scale display to real size >> screen size >> 6`

Answer (score 3):

This will do exactly what you would like to do, which is leave the emulator screen resolution alone while allowing you to scale the emulator window.

- Select the menu item `Window/Android SDK and AVD Manager/Start`
- Check `Scale display to real size`, (you can then set the *screen size* in inches on this page)
- Click `Launch`.
- The skin size the way you want it will appear, no app will be running. Wait for the launch to complete. Eclipse and Windows might not be not happy if you try to start your app during the skin launch.
- Start your app (with <kbd>F11</kbd> for instance).
- You may get a dialog about attaching to a running emulator. Do so.

Answer (score 3):

This is simplest one

1. Go to `Run`
2. Open command prompt
3. Type: `telnet localhost 5554 or telent localhost EMULATORID`
4. Then you will get Android console
5. Type this command `window scale 0.7` or `window scale <value from 0 to 1>`.

And if you are using Windows 7 then you have to first activate your telnet client.
for this follow these steps:

1. Go to control panel
2. There is icon named `Programs` below that `Uninstall program` is there click on it.
3. Then click on the turn Windows features on or off at left most to your screen
4. One list will be pop up just tick on the telnet client
5. And then click on <kbd>OK</kbd>
6. For testing go to command prompt and type `telnet` if you will not get error then telnet is working

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio (0.6.1 at time of writing):

1. Click Run>Edit Configurations
2. Select module you want to alter under 'Android Application' expandable list on left
3. Click 'Emulator tab
4. Make sure 'Additional command line options' is selected and type: -scale 0.5
5. Hit 'OK' and run your app!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with Android Studio is:
- launch the adv manager
- Select the emulator line you want
- hit the edit button on the right (a pencil)
- In the middle of the configuration screen that opens there is a Scale radio field - choose the ratio between device and screen that you prefer. I have chosen "4dp on device = 1px on screen" and the resulting size is just what I wanted (using Nexus 5).
- Hit Finish

Answer (score 0):

```
Run configurations-> target-> Addition emulator command text box 
write
"scale 0.6"
(without quotes)
```

Answer (score 0):

in linux is easy
[How do I launch the Android emulator from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line/30549142?stw=2#30549142)

you need to add at the end this "-scale 0.45"
for example: `/home/hackro/Documentos/Software/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd Android5.1.1  -scale 0.45`

I have shortcuts in my menu of the linux and they work well