# Changing Android Emulator Size to fit on my Screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

this may be a stupid question, but I've been doing Android Development for quite some time but just installed the new version of the SDK and ADT Eclipse plugin.

I've noticed that when I create a new AVD I can choose a specific device, I.e. Nexus 7 or Nexus Phone. I've selected the Galaxy Nexus but the emulator doesn't fit on the screen so I can't see the bottom of the device. At the moment I'm working on my Desktop which has a 21 inch monitor (1600 x 900) not the most highest spec in the world but I want to be able to fit the device on the screen. I also have a secondary screen which I usually keep the emulator on so I can see the code and the emulator, handy for debugging purposes, but this screen is much smaller and only has a resolution of 1280 x 800. At the moment, it would be impossible to press on the back and home buttons, and if I do development on my laptop, which is obviously a much smaller screen, probably wouldn't be able to see most of the device, as the AVD doesn't seem to scale to fit the screen.

Is there a way that this can be done. Below is a screen shot of how the device looks on my screen.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/android-emulator-screen-too-tall, see the answer here.  First hit for a Google "android emulator scale"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click your project -> Run Configuration -> select target -> in additional emulator command line option text box, type '-scale 0.75' and run your app

Answer (score 2):

For those using Ionic CLI or other solutions, the following worked for me:

```
ionic run android -scale=0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Android Studio*, the option is set in the AVD Manager, under "Startup size and orientation".