# Android Studio Emulator too big (Version 1.1.0)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently updated the android studio software to the latest 1.1.0 version and this has messed up the emulator setup. I've tried adding -scale 0.8 (used this number just to test if it would scale down) to the additional command line option but it just moves the position of the emulator to the right. Does anyone know if there's a work around to getting the emulator back to the previous emulator style or a way to reduce/fit the emulator to the size of my screen? Would just like to add if there's a way to move the emulator as is it seems to fix to one position on the screen?

You contribution is much appreciated.

Comment: When u open any emulator setting it will show option like 2dp = 2px on screen.. use preferred option from it. If you dont get it I will post screenshot.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly try using an emulator with a smaller screened device? Go in device manager and make a new device

Comment: Hi there, I've managed to reduce the screen size to just about fit using -scale 0.3. I tried from 1 to 0.4 and it didn't even move. I'll try making a using a screen device but i never required to do this until the recent update.

Comment: @Hamid you know at this point I'm not sure, but try running it on a smaller screen device and it should work better

Answer (score 1):

From Android studio, in `Run > Edit Configurations`, open the `Emulator` tab. In the field 'Additional command line options:', type `-scale 0.50` to get half size.
[image]

Comment: The newer version of Android Studio appears not to have the "Emulator" tab.