# Scale Emulator Size

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am a beginner in Android development. I would like to know whether it is possible to scale the emulator to the real size of the screen of your cellphone. If yes, how? For example, Google Nexus 5 has screen size of 5 inches, similarly, I would also like to have the screen size of my emulator to be 5 inches, so that, the App may look exactly similar in the Emulator, as it would look in the real cellphone.

I understand that the question might be very basic, but, I have just started learning Android development. I look forward to hear from you guys, thank you.

EDIT:
[image]

As you can see in the picture above, I would like to confirm if I check "Scale display to real size" check box, I automatically get an scale of 0.52. Does this scale automatically convert the emulator to the real screen size of the cellphone?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize the AVD emulator (in Eclipse)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-eclipse)

Comment: @ProkashSarkar: Eclipse. Also, please see the edit.

Comment: @Lal: Please have a look at the edit and confirm, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the "Scale display real size" should scale the emulator display into the real device display size. Additionally you can set a manual scale size by,

> Right click your project -> Run Configuration -> select target -> in
>   additional emulator command line option text box, type '-scale 0.75' or any preferable size