# Re-size Android emulator screen in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using Eclipse for developing a new application, I have problem with screen size in the Android emulator. Even if I create a new emulator the screen size is zoomed in as shown. I can't re-size it. Even after searching it I can't find any solution for it.

[image: Eclipse android emulator]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-eclipse follow this link and try to learn some research.

Comment: I am using windows 7 OS. can u help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Run > Run Configurations
Pick the "Target" tab
Scroll down to "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" and put in: "-scale 0.7" or another number
```

This will keep the AVD scaled even if it is started automatically by Eclipse.

try this

Comment: Thank you, but the scale size makes the whole emulator size small , can you give an idea to make my display screen zoom out. Thanks in advance

Comment: try the scale 1.25 instead of .75

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize the emulator like you do with a window. Instead, you can scale it in the AVD set up or via adb command. You can see it on the next screen (Launch Options) after you click the start button of an AVD. See [How to resize the AVD emulator in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-android-studio).

Comment: Thank you, but if re-size the scale the total emulator size becomes small.