# Eclipse AVD screen is zoom and merged

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, screen, android-virtual-device

I Run 'XXX' project in eclipse and before showing AVD it raises dialog box with **No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add new AVD? Yes or no Button** then I choose NO, Launch cancelled.

After this, if I run other projects in my workspace the AVD screen zoomed and icons are merged.

[image]

Then I deleted and recreate new AVD tried with different TARGETS and different Devices nothing works all are zoomed like above image

I'm not the only one:[AVD screen content is jumbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483841/avd-screen-content-is-jumbled) but there is no single solution.

If anyone came across this problem, give your solutions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-eclipse

Comment: Re-size is enough to clear this? I tried '-scale 0.75' solution not worked