# Create emulator with large screen size command line

Tags: android

For CI pipeline i need to create emulator with screen size of 1080*1920 but avd command line option accept skin size of only NNN*MMM at max . How to create emulator with such huge size command line options only.

I tried multiple options in avd :

```
android create avd -t <target-name> -s NNN*MMM -n some_name
```

Also looked at config.ini file but how to pass ini file while creating avd file

Answer (score -1):

Try using **Genymotion** as it is much better than the emulator coming with android studio and it is much faster than that.
Follow this [link](http://www.coderefer.com/how-to-install-genymotion/) to add genymotion as a plugin.

Comment: for Genymotion license is required and i need to run emulator in no ui mode

Comment: there is one free version also which will work perfect. Please try following this link i think it would solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359895/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-eclipse

Comment: scale options works only when you want to scale down not for increasing size